# Mysql operation between two table and want output in one

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two table `amount_to_pay` and `paid_amount` in `amount_to_pay` table data inserted as per `center_id` and `university_id` for which center for which university how much amount he has to pay and in `paid_amount` data inserted as which center for which university how much amount he paid, I want net amount pending from center for particular university as shown in third table below.

This is first table `amount_to_pay`

```
+---------+--------------+-------------+
|center_id|university_id |amount_topay |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
| 1       | 6            |29000        |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
| 1       | 7            |19700        |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
| 2       | 6            |9000         |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
```

This is my second table `paid_amount`

```
+---------+--------------+------------+
|center_id|university_id |amount_paid |
+---------+--------------+------------+
| 1       | 6            |9000        |
+---------+--------------+------------+
| 2       | 6            |5000        |
+---------+--------------+------------+
```

And want output as Below table

```
+---------+--------------+-------+
|center_id|university_id |amount |
+---------+--------------+-------+
| 1       | 6            |20000  |
+---------+--------------+-------+
| 1       | 7            |19700  |
+---------+--------------+-------+
| 2       | 6            |4000   |
+---------+--------------+-------+
```

Above amount_topay column is sum of amount_topay and group by center_id and university_id
In second table also amount_paid is sum of amount_paid column and group by center_id and university_id.

Comment: Your expected output doesnt seem correct please explain why 19700?

Answer (score 1):

You could join the tables and subtract the amounts. Note that you should use a `left join` so you don't miss entries where no payments have been made yet:

```
SELECT    a.center_id,
          a.university_id,
          a.amount_to_pay - COALESCE(p.amount_paid, 0) AS amount
FROM      amount_to_pay a
LEFT JOIN paid_amount p ON a.center_id = p.center_id AND 
                           a.university_id = p.university_id
```

Comment: @NileshsinhRathod care to elaborate on "not working"?

Comment: SELECT  a.fin_center_id,a.fin_university_id , (SUM( a.total_payable_amount )) - (sum(COALESCE(b.pay_amount,0))) AS total 
FROM (
finance_student_fees a
)
LEFT JOIN payment_from_center b ON (b.pay_center_id=a.fin_center_id AND b.pay_university_id=a.fin_university_id)
GROUP BY  a.fin_center_id,a.fin_university_id

Comment: can you help me for above query in comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join and  agroup by

```
select 
    a.center_id
  , a.university_id
  ,  sum(a.amount_topay) - sum(ifnull(b.amount_paid,0) as amount
from amount_to_pay as a
left join paid_amount as b 
          on a.center_id = b.center_id 
                and a.university_id = b.university_id
group by  a.center_id, a.university_id
```

Comment: There is a typo `inull` should be `isnull`.

Comment: @endo64   . yes  is a typo but is ifnull .. thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple one & Make sure you have applied unique key for `center_id` and `university_id` combination

```
SELECT 
    a.center_id
  , a.university_id
  ,  SUM(a.amount_topay)- SUM(inull(b.amount_paid,0) AS amount
FROM amount_to_pay AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN paid_amount AS b 
          ON(a.center_id = b.center_id 
                AND a.university_id = b.university_id)
GROUP BY  a.center_id, a.university_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT p1.center_id,p1.university_id,p1.amount_topay,p2.amount_paid,
CASE WHEN p1.center_id = p2.center_id AND p1.university_id = p2.university_id then amount_topay - amount_paid
     WHEN p1.center_id <> p2.center_id and p1.university_id <> p2.university_id then amount_topay 
     END as total 
     FROM amount_to_pay p1
     LEFT JOIN paid_amount p2
     ON amount_topay > amount_paid
     GROUP BY total HAVING total is not null
     ORDER BY total desc;
```

[see demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d5389/3)